# How to sum up values in a column for each week number?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to sum up values from Money column for each WeekNumber.

Now I have view:

```
WeekNumber  |   DayTime    |   Money 
---------------------------------------
1           |   2012-01-01 |    20.4
1           |   2012-01-02 |    30.5
1           |   2012-01-03 |    55.1
2           |   2012-02-01 |    67.3
2           |   2012-02-02 |    33.4
3           |   2012-03-01 |    11.8
3           |   2012-03-04 |    23.9
3           |   2012-03-05 |    34.3
4           |   2012-04-01 |    76.6
4           |   2012-04-02 |    90.3
```

Tsql:

```
SELECT datepart(week,DayTime) AS WeekNumber, DayTime, Money FROM dbo.Transactions
```

In conclusion, I would like to get something like this:

```
WeekNumber  |   DayTime    |    Sum
---------------------------------------
1           |   2012-01-01 |    106
2           |   2012-02-02 |    100.7
3           |   2012-03-03 |    470
4           |   2012-04-01 |    166.9
```

DayTime should be random for each Week Number but exists in column DayTime from view above.

Please, be free to write your ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT datepart(week,DayTime) AS WeekNumber
     , MIN(DayTime) DayTime  --<-- Instead of random get first date from your data in that week
     , SUM(Money) AS [Sum] 
FROM dbo.Transactions
GROUP BY datepart(week,DayTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT datepart(week,DayTime) AS WeekNumber, SUM(Money) FROM dbo.Transactions GROUP BY WeekNumber
```

As you will have number of rows for each week you cannot get DayTime with the same table. There are other ways to add that too like `JOIN`

Comment: This will throw you an error because you are not using group by

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL to sum the money column. Like this

```
SELECT 
datepart(week,DayTime) AS WeekNumber, 
DayTime, Money = SUM(Money) 
FROM dbo.Transactions
GROUP BY datepart(week,DayTime),DayTime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT datepart(week, DayTime) AS WeekNumber
    ,MIN(DayTime)
    ,SUM(MONEY)
FROM dbo.Transactions
GROUP BY datepart(week, DayTime)
```